# How to add a string present in different files to a empty list in python

Tags: python, scripting

1. To find a string present in different files.
2. Copy all occurrence of that string in a new file .

For example :- If "Hello_World" is present in 10 different files than first we should find it & than copy it to New File i.e. Searched_Strings.txt like

1.Hello_world
2.Hello_world
3,Hello_world
4.Hello_world
5.Hello_world
and so on..

Comment: Your question is unclear: are you looking for a specific string, or for any string present in several files (which would present many problems); furthermore, you're expected to provide at least some starting code you tried.

Comment: A [mcve] would help

Comment: Hi @Swifty ,
Pls find my code below just for searching the string 
import os
dir_path = r'D:\random_folder\python_source_code\'
# iterate each file in a directory
for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
    cur_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
    # check if it is a file
    if os.path.isfile(cur_path):
        with open(cur_path, 'r') as file:
            # read all content of a file and search string
            if 'Hello_World' in file.read():
                print('string found')
                break

Comment: Suppose the string "Hello_World" is present in different files than I want to print all its occurrence in separate file.

Comment: Please update your question by 1. including the code you posted in a comment and 2. stating your goal more clearly (which specific string you're looking for, info on the files you want to search in (names, folder they're in...), info on the output, and an example.